# Error while deleting multiple records in database ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following is the code in which i want to delete multiple records but getting error...
my view named `um_org_data` in which the code from the html file name is `index.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag destroy_um_org_data_path, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete all these?' } do %>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Organization Name</th>
            <th>Organization Description</th>
            <th>Office Address</th>
            <th>Office Phone Number</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>


         <% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "deleted_ids[]", um_org_data.id %></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.org_name %></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.org_description%></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.offc_addr%></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.offc_ph%></td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to "<i class='icon-eye-open'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data,"data-original-title" => "View Details", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>
                <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-edit'></i>".html_safe, edit_um_org_datum_path(um_org_data), "data-original-title" => "Edit", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none'%>

                <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-trash'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, "data-original-title" => "Delete", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>



              </td>
          </tr>

        <%end%>
        </table>
        <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn") do %>
           Delete Selected <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

and for this my controller name `um_org_data_controller.rb`
has the following method against this action.

```
def destroy
    @um_org_datum = UmOrgDatum.find(params[:id])
    @um_org_datum.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to um_org_data_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

i am facing error in the very first line of the view name `index.html.erb`

the following is the detail of error that i found.

```
NameError in Um_org_data#index

undefined local variable or method `destroy_um_org_data_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004582a10>:0x007fa9e42f4e38>

 <%= form_tag destroy_um_org_data_path, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete all these?' } do %>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
           <tr>
             <th></th>
```

where as delete below in the view code is working fine......
Thanks in Advance.

now after changing in my code.....

```
<%= form_tag url: destroy_selected_um_org_data_path, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete all these?' } do %>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Organization Name</th>
            <th>Organization Description</th>
            <th>Office Address</th>
            <th>Office Phone Number</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>


         <% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "um_org_data_ids[]", um_org_data.id %></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.org_name %></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.org_description%></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.offc_addr%></td>
              <td><%= um_org_data.offc_ph%></td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to "<i class='icon-eye-open'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data,"data-original-title" => "View Details", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>
                <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-edit'></i>".html_safe, edit_um_org_datum_path(um_org_data), "data-original-title" => "Edit", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none'%>

                <%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-trash'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, "data-original-title" => "Delete", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>



              </td>
          </tr>

        <%end%>
        </table>
        <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "btn") do %>
           Delete Selected <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

the controller code is following:

```
def destroy_selected
    @um_org_data = UmOrgData.find(params[:um_org_data_ids])
    @um_org_data.each { |o| o.destroy }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to um_org_data_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end

  end
```

and the error is following:

```
 NameError in Um_org_data#index

undefined local variable or method `destroy_selected_um_org_data_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004663bf0>:0x0000000466d3a8>

<%= form_tag url: destroy_selected_um_org_data_path, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete all these?' } do %>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
           <tr>
            <th></th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper method for deletion that gets generated by a resource route is basically the same helper method as for the `show` action only with `method: :delete`, hence there is no `destroy_*` helper method.

I.e., you would use: `link_to um_org_data_path(um_org_data), method: :delete`

But what you're trying to achieve doesn't work that way. Since the `destroy` method only works on a single object (it expects an ID), not a collection of objects. So I guess you would need something like this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :um_org_data do
  collection do
    delete :destroy_selected
  end
end

# um_org_data_controller.rb
class UmOrgDataController < AC::Base
  def destroy_selected
    @um_org_data = UmOrgData.find(params[:um_org_data_ids])
    @um_org_data.each { |o| o.destroy }
    # ...
  end
end

# index.html.erb
<%= form_tag url: destroy_selected_um_org_data_path, method: :delete do %>
  <% @um_org_data.each do |um_org_data| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "um_org_data_ids[]", um_org_data.id %></td>
    # ...
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: does nothing.... as the same is working in other code, but dont know why generating errors while i try many different codes

Comment: What do you mean "does nothing"? Do you get another error? The same?

Comment: That's impossible. Do you still use the `destroy_um_org_data_path` method somewhere? If so: DON'T! It doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, then you can't have the *same* error... Are you sure it's exactly the *same*?

Comment: now there is no way to show all my code again... so u have to trust on me

Comment: now check the question i have edited with the code u told to do!

Comment: Well that is not the *same* error. It says it can't find the new helper method... Can you post your `rake routes` outpout as well, please?

Comment: sorry there was a syntax error in route file that why having problem... now i got the its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Your path in the following `link_to` is not correct:

```
<%= link_to "<i class= 'icon-trash'></i>".html_safe, um_org_data, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, "data-original-title" => "Delete", "data-placement" => "bottom", :rel => "nofollow", :class => 'bg-color-none' %>
```

Try to replace:

```
um_org_data
```

by

```
um_org_data_path(um_org_data)
```

Comment: "<%= form_tag destroy_um_org_data_path, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete all these?' } do %>"

this is the line having error.!

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with the error OP asks about, it still is true. The path helper is expecting to work on a single object.